# Getting this error while testing my component using react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, integration-testing

### Getting this error while testing

> Error: matchMedia not present, legacy browsers require a polyfill

```
      3 | import * as ConfigConstants from '../../constants/config'
      4 | import {animatePots} from '../helpers/common'
    > 5 | import Slider from "react-slick";
        | ^
      6 | import {connect, ReactReduxContext} from 'react-redux'
      7 | import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
      8 | import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

I have my package.json as

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3002 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!amcharts)/\"",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "clear_jest": "jest --clearCache"
    
  },
```

And also testsetup.js as

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
    writable: true,
    value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
      matches: false,
      media: query,
      onchange: null,
      addListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
      removeListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
      addEventListener: jest.fn(),
      removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
      dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
    })),
  });
```

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/blob/5fb7ac78321f3469118a974af3852742b64fcbd3/docs/common.md#test-setup?

Comment: What did make you think that testsetup.js will be loaded? A proper name for the file in CRA is setupTests.js, and it should be located in a specific place.

Comment: It is still  not working @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate(!) .js file with beneath code and import it before(!) importing Slider (or any other crashing import). Solution found here: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    removeListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
  })),
});
```